QEMU clipboard not working
I have Debian 12 (Gnome on Wayland) as my host OS and the same Debian 12 as guest (via tty, no GUI). Using virt-manager and qemu-kvm for managing VMs. Tried installing spice-vdagent on guest but it is still not working. Tried executing spice-vdagent and enabling it in systemctl but still no success. Am I missing something?

Sounds like duplicate of KVM clipboard sharing with client running Wayland

@StéphaneChazelas I think the problem in my case is that I am running guest on bare tty, i just don't use X server. Guess I just wanted to know if it was possible to have a shared clipboard without GUI. Seems like it just doesn't work that way. It is actually not a big deal since I figured out that it is possible to simply SSH into VM, which is completely fine for me.
